# Are fonts and background-images part of the critical rendering path?

Tags: html, css, browser

Correct me if I have gotten this wrong please. I know that in the CRP there are resources that are needed in order for the browser to display the above the fold part of a page for the first time. Yet, I am under the impression that fonts* and background-images are not render blocking resources. Hence, I conclude that they are not part of the critical rendering path. Do I understand the concept correctly?

**I am aware about fonts being text-blocking resources and the 3sec barrier some browsers introduce.*

Thank you in advance for your guidance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course.
Although they are not blocking they have to be downloaded (it is recommended to use proper size images, compression, and formats, don't download unneeded fonts,...)

Also the layout phase in CRP has to use this elements when "painting" the page.